# React Native PanResponder not working on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, device

For some reason, I cannot make the PanResponder on my Android device. I use a Motorola Moto E (2nd gen) with Android 5.0.2

I was able to make this work on Android emulators (Nexus 6: Android 5.1 and Nexus S: Android 4.4) and on iOS Simulator and Device.

Any idea why the `PanResponder` doesn't work on device?

Some code here just in case it's needed. None of the `console.log` works on the device:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.panResponder = this.getPanResponder();
}

getPanResponder() {
    return PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
            console.log('start');
            return true;
        },
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
            console.log('start capture');
            return true;
        },
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
            console.log('move');
            return true;
        },
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
            console.log('move capture');
            return true;
        },
        onPanResponderMove: () => {
            console.log('moving');
        }
     })
}

render() {
    return (
        <View
            style={styles.container}
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
        </View>
    )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you already solved your problem? I have the same problem

Comment: No I didn't find a solution.

Comment: react-native is full of bugs

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and in my case what solved the problem is setting a backgroundColor to the view with the pan responder handlers. If you can't make it colorful (as I couldn't), just set the backgroundColor to something unnoticeable, like `rgba(255,255,255,0.01)`

It seems that android ignores pan responder handlers on transparent views

Comment: nice suggestion. PanResponder does not trigger with transparent view!

Comment: This answer worked for me, do you have the the link to official documentation to this?

Comment: cool.. it works! I too am looking for the link you learned this.

Comment: Wow you are a life saver! This fixed it.

Comment: You saved my life. :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems, onResponder... callbacks only works after grant current view as responder, i.e you should return true from one of these callbacks (dependent on gesture type and event phase): onStartShouldSetResponder, onStartShouldSetResponderCapture, onMoveShouldSetResponder, onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture. In my opinion this is a quite correct behaviour.